Network interface changes not seen in docker container
I'm running a distributed system that uses a pseudo-microservices architecture using docker containers. We use Data Distributed Service (DDS) as our transport layer; at the lowest level this just sends UDP messages between computers. The computers also have redundant networking, so when a NIC is lost the apps on that panel tell apps on the other panels they can't be reached that way anymore, so the distributed apps just ignore the downed interface.
We've written a simple interface checker in C that just prints out whenever an interface change is detected. I run it on the host system and the app prints out when I unplug a cable. I mount and run it within one of my containers, no change is reported.
My best guess is that this is caused by the way the docker daemon routes the networking to the containers. I'm already using --network host when I launch my containers.
I tried finding some resources, but most docker networking resources just explain the difference between host, bridged, etc.
Is there a docker setting or would this be an os level/iptables problem?
